# OpenEars Text-to-Speech very low quality

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, openears

I am designing an English dictionary-like app and using [OpenEars TTS](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) for pronunciation but the voice quality is not so good. Any suggestion to improve its sound quality?

Comment: I guess best place to ask this would be the forum on their site. But isn't their TTS ment more of a tool that helps their speech recognition engine to do it's work. I don't think it is ment to be used the way you're trying to.

Comment: What is your recommendation for TTS in iOS?

Comment: Yuji provided a link to private API and to another question with many suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9939686/653513). Didn't try any of those but the accepted answer seems promising.

Comment: "But isn't their TTS ment more of a tool that helps their speech recognition engine to do it's work." Nah, it's intended to be used just as DavidNg is using it (OpenEars has a separate TTS class from its speech recognition class), but not everyone likes the Flite voices. DavidNg, did you try the 16-bit slt voice? Most developers seem to like it best out of the Flite voices.

Comment: @Halle: what is "16-bit slt voice" ?

Comment: There are 8 voices in OpenEars' FliteController class, have you tried them all? The 16-bit slt voice is the one selected with the string @"cmu_us_slt" (not @"cmu_us_slt8k"). If you have more questions for me, do me a favor and bring them over to the OpenEars forum.

Comment: @Halle: I see, OK, I will change to this setting to see how good it is

Comment: You can download different voices here .. https://bitbucket.org/Politepix/openearsextras/src

Comment: Why not use native ios siri tts?

Answer (score 3):

If you are supporting iOS7 and above, you can consider using [AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is contact them directly and state your problem. Here is the link to their contact site: http://www.politepix.com/contact/

The best way to get your question answered is in their forums and here is the link for that: http://www.politepix.com/forums/forum/openearsforum/

They also have a private support service but that will cost you some money but here is the link for that: http://www.politepix.com/shop/openears-support-incident/