# ios, turn on VoiceOver programmatically

Tags: ios, ios7, accessibility

I'm building an app that will run in kiosk mode as part of an instillation with the home button covered.

I would like to give the user the ability to turn VoiceOver on if required.

Is it possible to do this programmatically?

**Edit for clarification**

I don't wish to just turn on the voice synthesizer, rather I would like to turn on all the features that are enabled with enabling of the VoiceOver accessibility option, this includes changing the way that touch events are reacted to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939589/how-to-programmatically-use-ios-voice-synthesizers-text-to-speech

Comment: Thanks for the link I had found that previously, it's a great reference for getting AVSpeechSynthesizer working but I guess I should have been more specific, enabling VoiceOver completely changes how the user interacts with the device. Scrolling and touch events are interpreted differently and I don't want to have to recreate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to turn VoiceOver on programatically.