# voice to text conversion using siri

Tags: ios, text, ios6, voice-recognition

For higher version of iOS the keyboard that arrives when clicking a textView or textfield contains a microphone icon which does speech to text conversion
 my question is whether it is possible to use this feature which is provided by apple in my app which does voice to text conversion on clicking on a button.how can i do this.

thanks in advance

Comment: This post might be helpful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686897/text-to-speech-on-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, try to view this post. It has so much useful information. 
Siri is not available in API form yet, however, any UITextField or UITextArea can be dictated to using the built-in option for speech-to-text.

[iPhone: Speech Recognition is in IOS SDK available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823693/iphone-speech-recognition-is-in-ios-5-sdk-available)

Comment: Let me know if it resolves your issue:)